# how can I have renko data from OHLC?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, yahoo-finance, algorithmic-trading

hello guys hope you're doing well,
I used a code to convert OHLC to collecting Renko data for tock using pd and yfinance
but how I can use the code for excel data ? the code is down below:

the code link:
https://github.com/techietrader/Trading-indicators-and-Chart-patterns/blob/master/Examples/Renko%20with%20an%20example.ipynb